# Adding the HTML code as String in VBA But Text is Red Highlighted

Tags: html, vba

I want to add this HTML code into VBA but the all text is in `RED` highlighted format how to make this valid in VBA window any help will be appreciated.

Is there anyway to create automaticaly joint in Excel vba to use this code into VBA.

```
    ThisHString = "[HTML CODE](https://docs.google.com/document/d/13Hr0aird5XjomeFwL0jz5P5Dm4jWq_w72hPpVh1nEys/edit)
```

Trying to enabling the HTML text as String in VBA. The code is too long how to add underscores at the last of every row to make joint for the next line.

[image]

Comment: There's no closing quote...  Not clear what you mean by "create automaticaly joint in Excel vba"

Comment: When i paste this into VBA module it all get break. Then i add joint with _at the last of every new row but it is very lengthy process.

Comment: Have you considered storing it in a worksheet cell instead (will hold up to up to 32k characters)?   You can reference it from there.  Alternatively, some text editors have a "copy special" utility which will format multi-line text for various languages (by adding quotes etc)

Comment: Yeah great idea. Thanks you let me check.

Comment: I tried but still not luck.

Comment: "no luck" tells us nothing about what happened when you tried that.  If you want help you need to first provide details.

Comment: Sir i tried with two editors and pasting the HTML code in cell as well but still the Red highlighted text is not removed.

Comment: Text pasted in a cell would not be checked for syntax.

Comment: Yes it just populated the sentences.

Comment: If you paste the text in A1 on the sheet "HTML" then in your VBA you have: `ThisHString =Thisworkbook.Worksheets("HTML").Range("A1").Value`

Comment: Yeah i got your point but i need all the syntax in the HTML code.

Comment: I'm really not understanding what the problem is here.  What are you actually *doing* with this HTML?

Comment: I hope this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67884801/trying-to-place-the-right-names-in-creathtml-function-from-html  may answer you well that what i am trying to do with the HTML code But i understand one more thing that i am missing & _ this and in last so i will try with this if it may work,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example where the HTML is stored in a file "Test.html" in a "Templates" folder located in the same location as the workbook where your code is running.

```vb
Public Function CreateHtml(ProductName As String, Condition As String, _
                           Description1 As String, Description2 As String) As String
    Dim TemplateString As String
    Dim HtmlValuesRecord As HtmlValues
    Dim defs As String

    TemplateString = GetContent(thisworkbook.path & "\Templates\Test.html")
    
    HtmlValuesRecord = GetHtmlValues(Category, defs, Conditionone)
    
    CreateHtml = TemplateString
    CreateHtml = Replace(CreateHtml, "{product-content}", ProductName)
    CreateHtml = Replace(CreateHtml, "{Like New}", Condition)
    CreateHtml = Replace(CreateHtml, "{grade-description}", HtmlValuesRecord.Description1)
    CreateHtml = Replace(CreateHtml, "{Product description}", HtmlValuesRecord.Description2)
    
End Function

'read all content from a file
Function GetContent(f As String) As String
    GetContent = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject"). _
                  opentextfile(f, 1).readall()
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the solution but i have to use it in the VBA Module